# Moving to use Claims Identity in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, claims-based-identity, iidentity

In our current system (.net 4.5) to handle user authentication throughout the app we have created our own `IIdentity` and `IPrincipal` objects. So on every request we decrypt an attribute in the cookie (stored at login) and using this we check the cache for the user object (which also provides us with the client object). If the user is in the cache, great we then set the `HttpContextBase.User` and the `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` to be our own version of `IPrincipal`. If the user isn't in the cache then we get them from the db and set the above.

This works really well as we then have a `BaseController` with 2 properties, one for the current user and one for the current client. These are accessed by casting `User.Identity` to our own `IIdentity`.

We are now looking to move our app over to .netcore but we are not sure how to achieve the same as above given that we don't seem to be able to replicate it. We are currently using cookie middleware with ASP Identity ([Shown Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie)), we are setting some claims (id, name etc) but we aren't sure how to or where we should be checking the cache and setting some properties on every request.